# Hibernate foreign key relation mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Hibernate generate foreign key by itself, but I have to have a declared foreign key field in my entity object. For example:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
private Integer customerId;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "CUSTOMER_ID"), referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private CustomerEntity customer;
```

But this generate :

> Repeated column in mapping for entity:
> AccountEntity column: CUSTOMER_ID (should be
> mapped with insert="false" update="false")

But if i set customerId with

> insert="false" update="false"

It tries to insert NULL value.

How I can do this?

Comment: Are you generate a schema from entities, I don't think `foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")` is  needed atAll

Comment: You have to decide if you want a proper object model where entities refer to other entities and foreign keys are just a database concept to link entities (so, removing the explicit `customerId` field from your entity) or fall back to a more technical view and remove the `customer` field but both is redundant and does not match Hibernate concepts.

Comment: @Smutje But if I remove customer field, I cannot have LAZY relationship because for db aren't linked.

Comment: What? That does not make any sense - if you make a join manually that is as lazy as it can get.